# How to convert a hex TimeDateStamp DWORD value into human readable format?

Tags: portable-executable

Can anyone explain how to convert a Hex TimeDateStamp DWORD value into human readable format?

I'm just curious as to how a value such as 0x62444DB4 is converted into
"Wednesday, 30 March 2022 10:31:48 PM"

I tried googling of course and could not find any explanation. But there are online converters available.

But I'm just interested in converting these values for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your value is a 32-bit Timestamp.

Your datetime value is a 32-bit Unix Timestamp: The number of seconds since 1/1/1970.
See https://unixtime.org/

In most programming languages you can work with the hexadecimal notation directly.
Implementation should not be done by one person alone, since a lot of engineering goes into it. Leap years, even leap seconds, timezones, daylight savings time, UTC... all these things need to be addressed when working with a timestamp.
I have added my rough calculation below as a demonstration. Definitely use an existing package or library to work with timestamps.

See the JavaScript code below for demonstration.
There I multiply your value by 1000 because JavaScript works in Milliseconds. But otherwise this applies the same to other systems.

```js
let timestamp = 0x62444DB4;
let dateTime = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
console.log('Timestamp in seconds:', timestamp);
console.log('Human-Readable:', dateTime.toDateString() + ' ' + dateTime.toTimeString());

// Rough output, just for the time.
// Year month and day get really messy with timezones, leap years, etc.
let hours = Math.floor(timestamp/3600) % 24;
let minutes = Math.floor(timestamp/60) % 60;
let seconds = Math.floor(timestamp) % 60;
console.log('Using our own time calculation:', hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

Comment: Wow thanks man. I definitely didn't think of leap years. Also thanks for giving me the name of the value. 32bit Unix timestamp. So this value is the number of seconds from 1st of January 1970 to whenever something is compiled. Thanks again man.

Comment: Sure you're welcome 